# Select list item -> load a custom page based on permissions

Tags: sharepoint

I'm using Windows SharePoint Services. My list shows items, and I need to direct the user to a specific page according to their permission level.

For example, I'm showing a list of jobs. 
If I am a job seeker (visitor permissions), when I select the job from the list, show some details about the job, do not allow them to change anything, and display a 'Apply for this job' button.
If I am a job poster (member permissions), show my jobs only, let me select the job, then let me edit all details about the job.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One option you can consider using is [Custom Action](http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2007/06/23/sample-editcontrolblock-customaction-for-sharepoint.aspx).

In the custom Action you can control when the Menu items is displayed to the user based on the logged in user permission Level (Refer to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194.aspx) for complete list of attributes that comes with Custom Action).

When the user click on the Menu Item you can redirect him to the Page and show the content with (Button/edit option) in that page. You will also need to validate if the user has that permission to make sure that User is not tricking and landing to that page.

Note:You have to take on what type of the Item you apply this custom action because it will be applied to all the List items in the Site if you apply to the generic List Item, you can try creating a custom content type for the List Item(Job) and apply it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a feature which contains a custom list definition. Together with a list definition you can not only define you list and columns, but you can also customize the forms that are shown when you create, edit or simply display a list item.

So this might be an option to solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just define in the list that you can only edit items that you created and give the job posters contribute acces and the job seekers read acces.

No development needed and it does what you want. Of course selecting an item will always give you the view screen, but there the job poster can select edit item.